# Is the Coefficient of Determination the "explained variance" or the ratio of explained variance to total variance

Tags: variance, r-squared

I have found in multiple texts that the coefficient of determination, or R-squared, is often referred to as the "variance explained". When, to be precise, it seems to be the ratio of the variance explained to the total variance.

Wouldn't the variance explained be the total variance - unexplained variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total variance decomposes into the explained variance and unexplained variance (more complicated than this if you deviate from ordinary least squares, but I think you’re in that setting).

$$
\text{Total Variance}=\text{Unexplained Variance} + \text{Explained Variance}
$$

These often go by other terms, total sum of squares (TSS), sum of squared residuals (SSRes) and sum of squares of the regression (SSReg).

$$
TSS = SSRes + SSReg
$$

Then…

$$
R^2=\dfrac{SSReg}{TSS}=\dfrac{TSS-SSRes}{TSS}\\
=1-\dfrac{SSRes}{TSS}
$$

You’re right that unexplained variance is total variance minus explained variance, but that is contained in the equation for $R^2$. If you learned a different way to calculate $R^2$, it would be equivalent to what I gave above, even if the equivalence is not obvious.

If your reference says that $R^2$ is the explained variance, they are being a bit loose with their phrasing for my taste. While $R^2$ is related to the explained variance, the two are not synonyms.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave. Yes, I was working from the OLS context.

You answered my question completely.  It was really just a matter of wording. I understand that this information is contained within the R-squared and that they are similar ways of communicating the same underlying information. 

The TSS = SSRes + SSReg , could be stated in terms of variance instead of sum of squares by just dividing each portion by N. I was a little thrown because I could not find the formula stated this way - in terms of variance instead of SS.

Comment: Because I could not find a formula stating the variance explained (or variance from regression) as the total variance minus the residual variance, I assumed there was some rule keeping it from being stated like so. In which case, it would make sense that the coefficient of determination, or R-squared, took on the moniker 'variance explained' - because stating the variance explained as a value was not possible.

Comment: Glad to help! Yes, there’s a factor of sample size to get from the “total variance” equation to the “tots sim of squares” equation. I’m thinking of a way to phrase that in the answer and will edit to clarify if I do.